# Smart contracts in Dollars

Tags: currency, cryptocurrency, contract-theory

In last years I have read a lot about "[Smart contracts](http://www.fastcolabs.com/3035723/app-economy/smart-contracts-could-be-cryptocurrencys-killer-app)".

But I cannot understand why we need bitcoin for this?
The old-fashioned US Dollar are not used in Smart Contracts?

Answer (score 2):

I guess it depends on what precisely counts as "self-executing" but escrow transactions are very similar and quite common, particularly in real estate and certain kinds of online transactions.

> An escrow is a deposit of funds, a deed or other instrument by one
>   party for the delivery to another party upon completion of a specific
>   condition or event. It is an independent neutral account by which the
>   interests of all parties to the transaction are protected.

[What is Escrow? - Title One](https://www.titleonecorp.com/buyerseller/whatisescrow.aspx)